# Lifetime error when spawning a task

Tags: rust, lifetime

I can not understand this error regarding lifetimes. `Proxy` is a struct:

```
impl Proxy {
    pub fn new<A: ip::ToSocketAddr>(address: A) -> Proxy {
        Proxy {
            address: address.to_socket_addr().unwrap()
        }
    }

    pub fn listen_and_proxy(&self) {
        println!("listening {}", self.address);
        for stream in TcpListener::bind(self.address).listen().incoming() {
            let stream = stream.unwrap();
            spawn(move || { // <- this causes an error
                let mut stream = stream;
                let name = stream.peer_name();
                println!("client: {} -> {}", name, self.handle(stream));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Output error:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
```

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call `self.handle(stream)` which would require moving `self` into the newly spawned thread. This cannot be done.